# Where are the sql files of the default schemas (Oracle database)

Tags: sql, oracle, database-schema, sql-scripts

What is the location of the sql scripts of say, the emp table creation of the scott schema ?

Comment: SOLUTION:Follow this link docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC00002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/rdbms/admin`

Read the documentation for [Manually Installing Sample Schemas](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC00002)

For example, the **scott.sql** script is -

```
Rem Copyright (c) 1990 by Oracle Corporation
Rem NAME
REM    UTLSAMPL.SQL
Rem  FUNCTION
Rem  NOTES
Rem  MODIFIED
Rem gdudey     06/28/95 -  Modified for desktop seed database
Rem glumpkin   10/21/92 -  Renamed from SQLBLD.SQL
Rem blinden   07/27/92 -  Added primary and foreign keys to EMP and DEPT
Rem rlim       04/29/91 -         change char to varchar2
Rem mmoore     04/08/91 -         use unlimited tablespace priv
Rem pritto     04/04/91 -         change SYSDATE to 13-JUL-87
Rem   Mendels    12/07/90 - bug 30123;add to_date calls so language independent
Rem
rem
rem $Header: utlsampl.sql 7020100.1 94/09/23 22:14:24 cli Generic<base> $ sqlbld.sql
rem
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET ECHO OFF

rem CONGDON    Invoked in RDBMS at build time.   29-DEC-1988
rem OATES:     Created: 16-Feb-83

GRANT CONNECT,RESOURCE,UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO SCOTT IDENTIFIED BY TIGER;
ALTER USER SCOTT DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS;
ALTER USER SCOTT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP;
CONNECT SCOTT/TIGER
DROP TABLE DEPT;
CREATE TABLE DEPT
       (DEPTNO NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT PK_DEPT PRIMARY KEY,
    DNAME VARCHAR2(14) ,
    LOC VARCHAR2(13) ) ;
DROP TABLE EMP;
CREATE TABLE EMP
       (EMPNO NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT PK_EMP PRIMARY KEY,
    ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
    JOB VARCHAR2(9),
    MGR NUMBER(4),
    HIREDATE DATE,
    SAL NUMBER(7,2),
    COMM NUMBER(7,2),
    DEPTNO NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT FK_DEPTNO REFERENCES DEPT);
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES
    (10,'ACCOUNTING','NEW YORK');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (20,'RESEARCH','DALLAS');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES
    (30,'SALES','CHICAGO');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES
    (40,'OPERATIONS','BOSTON');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,to_date('17-12-1980','dd-mm-yyyy'),800,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('20-2-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),1600,300,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('22-2-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),1250,500,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7566,'JONES','MANAGER',7839,to_date('2-4-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),2975,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7654,'MARTIN','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('28-9-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),1250,1400,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7698,'BLAKE','MANAGER',7839,to_date('1-5-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),2850,NULL,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7782,'CLARK','MANAGER',7839,to_date('9-6-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),2450,NULL,10);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7788,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,to_date('13-JUL-87')-85,3000,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7839,'KING','PRESIDENT',NULL,to_date('17-11-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),5000,NULL,10);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7844,'TURNER','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('8-9-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),1500,0,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7876,'ADAMS','CLERK',7788,to_date('13-JUL-87')-51,1100,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7900,'JAMES','CLERK',7698,to_date('3-12-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),950,NULL,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7902,'FORD','ANALYST',7566,to_date('3-12-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),3000,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7934,'MILLER','CLERK',7782,to_date('23-1-1982','dd-mm-yyyy'),1300,NULL,10);
DROP TABLE BONUS;
CREATE TABLE BONUS
    (
    ENAME VARCHAR2(10)  ,
    JOB VARCHAR2(9)  ,
    SAL NUMBER,
    COMM NUMBER
    ) ;
DROP TABLE SALGRADE;
CREATE TABLE SALGRADE
      ( GRADE NUMBER,
    LOSAL NUMBER,
    HISAL NUMBER );
INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (1,700,1200);
INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (2,1201,1400);
INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (3,1401,2000);
INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (4,2001,3000);
INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (5,3001,9999);
COMMIT;

SET TERMOUT ON
SET ECHO ON
```

Comment: I couldn't find scott.sql. But I could find UTLSAMPL.sql.
What about PM schema files? are they under a different name? I tried grep on the files but couldn't find any!

Comment: Which version? Do you have the DBA account?

Comment: Use the `utlsampl.sql`.

Comment: Follow this link http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC00002